# Rails 4 detect if all the values in a column are the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am trying to see if all values in the column birth_date a given array @persons are the same. So I can see if this array contains all the same value for Person.birth_date.  I don't want to check if it's a SPECIFIC date, just if the birth_dates in the array of @persons are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniq` and `pluck` to do that:

```
puts Person.uniq.pluck(:birth_date).count == 1
```

You can also use `select` method

```
puts Person.select('DISTINCT birth_date').count == 1
```

Comment: I don't want to find the a unique record,  I want to see if every Person in the array @persons has the same Person.birth_date.  I do NOT want a unique birth_date

Comment: Ok.  Now that I 've had some sleep I see.  HA.